# 4 switch Buck-Boost, boost not reaching designed current

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I am working on a power supply that regulates the voltage coming out of a 3S LiPo battery. The buck portion of the circuit works fine and outputs 5+ A with acceptable ripple. The boost portion is giving me some problems.

I require it to work at 20 V, 5 A but it only works up to ~3  A, after that it starts making audible noise (even though the switching frequency is 300kHz) and one of the MOSFETs (HDVR1) instantly overheats.

From the datasheet of the device ([LM5175](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5175.pdf)) I know that the HDVR1 switch should be constantly conducting during boost operation and the mosfet that I used is rated at well over 3 A, so it should not heat up as it does.

The diagram of the circuit is pretty much a copy-paste of [this schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidroa8a/tidroa8a.pdf) from a [reference design](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP20042#0) by Texas Instruments.

[image: My schematic]

I am aware that it is likely to be a routing problem, but I don't know where to start. I did some analysis on the board, but it's not easy because the MOSFET fries after 4-5 seconds.

The FB signal does not change from buck to boost operation, and the waves on the SW1 and SW2 nodes seem to be OK. The signals on the gates of every MOSFET are as predicted and the rest of the board doesn't heat up.

During operation under 3 A measured efficiency is around 97%. All of that makes me think that there is not a clear and horrible error, but that something more subtle must be going on.

I received much help from reading answers to other questions in various situations in the past, but this time I have no idea of how to proceed.

EDIT 1:

On the gate of HDVR1 I get this behaviour during high load condition:

[image: HDVR1 high load]

@peufeu said that it should be around VIN+7V and at the beginning it's 18 V, which is right for a battery partially discharged.

The messy section on the left looks like this:

[image]

It lasts for around 6 ms, which doesn't mean anything to me. Also, it oscillates at ~27 kHz, which has little to do with the 300 kHz working frequency.

While on the right there's more or less this:

[image: HDVR1 high load - right part]

These are the BOOT1 and BOOT2 signals on no load operation:

[image: BOOT1 - no load]

[image: BOOT2 - no load]

While they are the same under load:

[image: BOOT1 - high load]

[image: BOOT2 - high load]

I'm adding here a couple of screenshots from the routing. I'm sorry if they are messy; this was planned to be a prototype.

[image: Only traces]

[image: Top traces and planes]

[image: Bottom traces and planes]

Comment: Measure bootstrap voltage close to or during that particular load situation. Measure/calculate duty-cycle.

Comment: If it's continuously conducting (no AC on SW1) you're not driving the bootstrap capacitor. If SW2 is always operating you may be able to connect a cap from SW2 to BOOT1 instead. If that doesn't exceed Vgs for HDVR1. Also, 20V 5A implies about 10A in HDVR1, is it rated (and heatsinked) for that current?

Comment: Your schematic is copy and paste, but what about BOM and PCB layout pattern?

Comment: Also, 3S gives only 10-14V, so to get 20 you always should be in boost mode. Why buck (and extra cost) should be in the picture?

Comment: @winny BOOT1 stays constant at VCC while BOOT2 oscillates near 0 during high discharge.
Duty-cycle instead oscillates wildly between 5-95%, that's most probably what's making the noise

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't understand why SW1 should not be constant. The datasheet says that during buck operation, LDVR1 is constantly off while HDVR1 is always on, thus I would expect constant voltage on SW1. Am I not getting it right?
HDVR1 is rated 50A at 100C and it's more or less cooled. What's strange is the discontinuity in the behavior, since it remains cool up to 3.5A and fries almost instantly at 4A.

Comment: @AliChen
BOM is pretty much the same, while the PCB layout is not. I copied the switching section though and followed the rules on sensible components placement. With that said, it's totally possible that it doesn't work because of the layout, since I have not much experience in switching applications.
Buck is needed because the voltage can be set to 5,9,15,20V for a USB-C PD application (that's also the purpose of the TI example from which the schematic comes from).

Comment: I didn't say SW1 shouldn't be constant. I DID say that if it is, it doesn't drive BOOT1 higher than VCC as it needs to be, if you are to turn HDRVR1 on properly. Check Vgs on HDRVR1 and I think you'll find that FET is turning partially off, which will kill it through excessive dissipation. Also compare SW1 voltage with VCC, I bet there's a bigger drop than you expect.

Comment: Yes, putting a scope probe on HVDR1 should help here, to have  Q1 stay on continuously, HVDR1 must stay at about VIN+7V... Put the probe in, then run the board for 1-2 seconds, don't let it burn, kill the power, and post the HVDR1 trace... If it goes down as the bootstrap cap discharges then you have your answer, but if this is the case, then how can this chip even boost? Weird...

Comment: @peufeu certainly looks weird to me, but as he says, the TI example design does this... downloading the LM5175 datasheet to see if it has anything to say now.

Comment: What's the voltage drop (D-S) across the FET that's frying, and the G-S voltage for that matter?

Comment: "BOOT2 oscillates near 0 during high discharge" There's your problem! Post oscillograms.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I check the datasheet, quickly though, and I still have no clue. I used a similar chip, LTC3780 to make a buck-boost LED driver and I remember the datasheet mentioning that it would pulse the FETs periodically to recharge the bootstrap caps. My first DC-DC converter, aaahhh the memories, LOL

Comment: I used the LM5175 in a previous design of mine (old job), had also some problems with stability under higher load currents. However, i heard from TI-support, there's a new LM5176, with an improved stability compared to the LM5175. Maybe ask support, or give the new chip a try.

Comment: "While trying to get the BOOT1 and BOOT2 on high load waves it suddenly stopped making noise and the current went up to value." Interesting. Did your probe push a cold solder joint and made it contact? Or layout problems?...

Comment: Does your inductor L1 match the BOM item from the reference design? Maybe it gets saturated as DC increases beyond its design capability?

Comment: I don't understand how you can mention in the question as well as the comments that it is probably a routing/layout problem, then omit everything that would let someone help you if it indeed is that problem.  Show us the PCB.  Or at least the critical switching node (the mosfets, input and output caps, and inductor in one screen shot).  If you're trying to protect the design... it doesn't work.  So anyone coming across this would only be able to rip off a bad layout and you'd still have a better, improved layout to keep to yourself (assuming someone can help you).

Comment: @winny I took some oscillograms and you can see that BOOT2 goes down to ~1V, even if for little time. Do you think that can be the cause? Also, that happens on BOOT2, which is not related to HDVR1...

Comment: @Franz Forstmayr Thanks for the tip! I'll give the new version a try as soon as I'm reasonably sure that it's not all my fault :)

Comment: @peufeu Yes I thought about cold joints and in fact I had already reflown the board but nothing happens. Also I'm mostly using 0805 components, but after inspecting several times the board I couldn't find anything...

Comment: @Ali Chen Yes I rechecked the datasheet and the nominal saturation current is 27A, so I think it should be fine for this application.

Comment: @metacollin You are totally right about that, I didn't upload that before because I couldn't add more images to the post, but I'm adding it now. I don't know if the visibility settings make the images understandable...

Comment: Not much decoupling on the input and output... also the gate traces are quite long could be oscillations? Looking at the traces, it looks like there is indeed a problem, but right now I have no idea what it could be ;)

Comment: @M.Mamo Yes indeed! 1 V is too low to turn in on, but when you are passing by the 2-4 V range you are driving it in the linear mode which can break your MOSFET very quickly. Can you limit your upper duty cycle limit and increase capacitance?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a TI WEBENCH of your design and find out where your schematic or PCB layout differs from the recommended WEBENCH schematic and layout. It only takes a few minutes and can shed some light on the issue very quickly.